# HoloLens - UI/Slider and Cursor do not intersect during gaze

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, cursor, hololens, gaze-buttons

I'm trying to use **UI/Slider** in Unity app for HoloLens.
I used the steps described here - [Unity UI on the HoloLens](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-ui-on-the-hololens.394629/)

So as a result I have following structure:

[image]

**MainCamera** properties:

[image]

**SliderCanvas** is using **MainCamera**:

[image]

**Slider** properties:

[image]

**InteractiveMeshCursor** is taken from HoloToolkit.

**As a result** I'm getting this picture:

[image]

When I move the head the **Cursor** behaves correctly - it stays in the middle of the scene. If I add other 3D objects on the Scene it also correctly changes its states so **GazeManager** looks like is working correctly.

However **I cannot gaze at Slider** because it moves with the **Camera** too and stays in the bottom/center of the scene where I want it to be. So in my case there is no way for them to intersect.

How can I fix this? Do I need to add an other Camera for the SliderCanvas but then how to control both cameras? I am definitely missing something and would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

As expected the solution turned out to be simple (I missed one step from the tutorial). For UI objects you need to set **Render Mode** property for the **Canvas** to **World Space** and changed the Position and Scale of the Slider. Now the Gaze is working.

SliderCanvas properties:

[image]

Slider properties:

[image]