# Cursor doesn't gaze on my UI Slider when deployed in the Hololens

Tags: unity-game-engine, uislider, hololens

Based on this repo https://github.com/qian256/ur5_unity. I am trying to get this working with some modifications, as I need. You can also see the issue in this repo.

I am unable to get the sliders move when I deploy it in the Hololens. I have a cursor that can gaze over the robot body but doesn't gaze on the slider bar or handle. I have tried most of the suggestions online including setting canvas to world-space.

I have already tried this out: [HoloLens - UI/Slider and Cursor do not intersect during gaze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43942382/hololens-ui-slider-and-cursor-do-not-intersect-during-gaze)

Comment: Does the sliders has a collider? Take in count that you may be a bit closer on the input control to take the gaze input.

Comment: can you provide your script so we can see what is being done?

Comment: Have you added the Holo Input Module to your canvas?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more, if you can debug, set a breakpoint, and try to determine which object is being hit by your raycast, If it is an object behind your slider, then you need to adjust the layer of your slider object to be the top most layer and not shared by other game objects. If it is your slider, you might try and use the pinch and hold event, and detect which direction the user is pulling and then adjust the slider value manually.

Answer (score 0):

The gaze would use `Physics.Raycast` thereby a `Collider` is required to gaze at somethiing. You can set quad primitives into your UI (with `Canvas` set to World Space with proper camera) by removing the `MeshRenderer` component but keeping the `Collider` one. You would then need to handle yourself gaze events for your UI e.g. gazing upper side of quad, you would manually move the slider up, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have 50 rep otherwise I would have commented but, I answered a very similar question here dealing with if your cursor goes through your UI element.

[In the canvas I loose the cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47450281/in-the-canvas-i-loose-the-cursor/47558808#47558808)

However, if the problem is just that you can't move the cursor then, you need to make sure you have subscribed to the scroll/manipulation events for your cursor. You can test this to see if this is the case by just clicking on the slider in a different spot and the slider should jump to the spot you clicked.